# How to select running total for each group in a query

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

```
SELECT  district_lease, 
        first_proddate, 
        prod_cnt, 
        @rt := @rt + prod_cnt AS api_cnt        
    FROM Temp1 a
    JOIN (SELECT @rt := 0) r
    GROUP BY district_lease, first_proddate
    ORDER BY district_lease, first_proddate ;
```

This query computes a running total not by group district_lease, first_proddate but a running total for the complete query. What we want is a running total for each district_lease and first_proddate.

Comment: can you pls share some data & expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Use  [`sum()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)function

Query:

```
SELECT  district_lease, 
        first_proddate, 
        prod_cnt, 
        sum(prod_cnt) AS api_cnt        
FROM Temp1 a
GROUP BY district_lease, first_proddate
ORDER BY district_lease, first_proddate ;
```